# Spring MVC HiddenHttpMethodFilter() does not call the method marked with @PatchMapping

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm just learning and everything works according to the lesson I'm watching. However, in my case, the server returns HTTP 405 Message Request method 'POST' not supported.

Problem: The "update" method has been added (everything works with the @PostMapping annotation):

```
package ru.first.spring.app.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import ru.first.spring.app.dao.PersonDAO;
import ru.first.spring.app.models.Person;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PeopleController {
    private final PersonDAO personDAO;

    public PeopleController(PersonDAO personDAO) {
        this.personDAO = personDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("people", personDAO.index());
        return "people/index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String show(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", personDAO.show(id));
        return "people/show";
    }

    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String newPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {
        return "people/new";
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public String create(@ModelAttribute Person person) {
        personDAO.save(person);
        return "redirect:/people";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
    public String edit(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", personDAO.show(id));
        return "people/edit";
    }

    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public String update(@ModelAttribute Person person, @PathVariable int id) {
        personDAO.update(id, person);
        return "redirect:/people";
    }

//    @PostMapping("/{id}")
//    public String update(@ModelAttribute Person person, @PathVariable int id) {
//        personDAO.update(id, person);
//        return "redirect:/people";
//    }

}
```

In order for this to work, the course author said to add HiddenHttpMethodFilter():

```
package ru.first.spring.app.config;

import org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext aServletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(aServletContext);
        registerHiddenFieldFilter(aServletContext);
    }

    private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter",
                new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*");
    }
}
```

Here is the edit.html where a hidden method is automatically created using thymeleaf (checked in the browser - it works):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Update person</title>
</head>
<body>
<form th:method="PATCH" th:action="@{/people/{id}(id=${person.getId()})}" th:object="${person}">
    <label for="name">Enter name</label>
    <input th:field="*{name}" type="text" id="name">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit person">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Given that everything works with the @PostMapping annotation, I logically assumed that it was HiddenHttpMethodFilter, which for some reason does not work.

I checked the code for errors, typos, etc. (since before that the server threw a similar error when I set the wrong path in th:action). I made sure that the application is working properly with the @PostMapping annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By replacing your own with the pom of the course author, everything worked.
Maybe it's the spring.version, I thought? No, just by changing the version I was getting the same error.
And if you change the version and add everything missing from build? That didn't work either. The problem was solved only by completely replacing mine pom.xml

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>spring.mvc.first.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>firstSpringMVCApp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>firstSpringMVCApp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <spring.version>5.3.20</spring.version>
  </properties>


  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>firstSpringMVCApp</finalName>
  </build>

</project>
```

Worked pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ru.alishev.springcourse</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-crud-app3</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>spring-mvc-app1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

    <spring.version>5.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>spring-mvc-app1</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <source>8</source>
                  <target>8</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This can hardly be called a full-fledged solution to the problem. I left it here, in case you have a similar error, perhaps editing the pom will help you.

Comment: It took just a few minutes and the server began to crash when starting with a new one pom.xml ... Magic outside Hogwarts ;)